# How can I run Protractor tests on a remote machine

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor, invoke-command

I want to run my protractor tests on a virtual machine. I already tried running it with the following command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.2.1.7 -Port 5985 -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock{
    protractor C:\Users\test\Desktop\proRemote\config.js
}
```

Unfortunately this approach is very slow. Is there another way to run my protractor tests on a virtual machine? Maybe with the remote webdriver of selenium (I could not figure out how to do the setup).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess this should solve the purpose. Add the following in your conf.js and run as a normal Protractor Test. seleniumAddress: 'http://10.2.1.7:5985/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sakshi Singla suggested I fired up a webdriver on my remote machine (be sure to open the port if you are on a Windows machine) and connect to that in my config file:

```
 multiCapabilities:[
        {"browserName": "chrome",
        "seleniumAddress": 'http://10.105.178.758:5555/wd/hub',
        },
    ],
```

Comment: Also selenium-server-standalone.jar should be running on your remote machine.